# Integral of an integrable function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be Reimann integrable. Define $G(x) = \int_a^x f$. Then $G$ is continuous. I tried to prove this. Can you please tell me if my proof is correct?

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$. Let the bound of $f$ be denoted by $M$. Let $\delta$ be such that $\delta M < \varepsilon$. Then $x \in (x_0 , x_0 + \delta)$ implies $|G(x)-G(x_0)| \le \int_{x_0}^x |f| \le \delta M <\varepsilon$. Similarly if $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0)$. Hence $G$ is continuous.

Comment: Do you mean $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous?

Comment: I don't think you need $f$ continuous to get that $G$ is continuous.

Comment: Also:  $f$ might not be bounded.

Comment: I think he might be requiring Riemann integrability so I think it has to be bounded.

Comment: AH! Much easier.

Comment: This is good aside from stating "WLOG assume $x_0\le x$" which you can justify because you can switch the subtrahend and minuend inside the $|G(x)-G(x_0)|$ expression if necessary.

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ is integrable? Which sort of integration do you mean, Riemann or Lebesgue? The result is true either way, but the proof needs an extra step with the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Write $$|G(x)-G(x_0)| \le \left|\int_{x_0}^x |f|\right| \le \delta M <\varepsilon$$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank you for comments, I tried to correct the typos. Is better now?

Comment: Note that my previous comment works for every $x \in \,]x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta[$ .